# Angular4 httpclient error Type 'Observable<Observable<Object>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Am using angular4 http client fetching data from server but am getting an error of

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<Object>>' is not assignable to type 
  'Observable<boolean>'.
```

On the http request i have

```
  saveCredit(data): Observable<boolean> {

   return this._http.post(this.authurl + 'auth/save-credit', data)
     .map((res) => {
    return Observable.of(res);
      }, (err) => {
       return Observable.of(false)
     });
  }
```

On the server after save am returning true or false.What elese do i need to do so that i can simply use the above method via

```
this._acceeService.saveCredit(data).subscribe((res)=>{
   ...do my stuff here
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this._http.post()` already return an observable so, to this function, you must return a boolean to get an observable of boolean.

Try something like that:

```
saveCredit(data): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._http.post(this.authurl + 'auth/save-credit', data).map(
        res => !!res,
        err => false
    );
}
```

Comment: i see i changed return res to return !!(res) and now it works thanks

Comment: Yes, of course, you must take care to return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an observable inside your observable.

You can just return the first observable without creating another one inside it. And use the catch operator for error handling.

```
saveCredit(data): Observable<boolean> {
   return this._http.post(this.authurl + 'auth/save-credit', `enter code here`data).catch(this.handleError)  
}  

public handleError = (error: Response) => {            
    // Do messaging and error handling here
    return Observable.throw(error)
}
```

**Or** if you want to use an Observable inside the other just use the flatMap Operator

```
this._acceeService.saveCredit(data)
.flatMap(res=>res)
.subscribe((res)=>{
   ...do my stuff here
})
```